# Update Rows in RadGrid asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net

I have binded data in RadGrid. I want to check multiple checkboxes and value inserted in textboxes in grid column should be inserted in database though single button based on checked checkboxes.
is it only possible through foreach loop and findcontrol in it. Please Help keeping performance of grid in mind.
Thank you very much